# constraining Rows and Columns in Numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop

Below is code which would ideally find the smallest # of rows and greatest # of columns of all inputted arrays, then constrain all inputted arrays to these dimensions (filling in zeros, if needed)

I realize there's some kind of problem with the last two for loops..

Any help hugely appreciated!

```
def resize(*args):

sizes_0=np.zeros((len(args)))
sizes_1=np.zeros((len(args)))


#STANDARDIZE SHAPE  

for x in range(0, len(args)):

    sizes_0[x]=args[x].shape[0]
    sizes_1[x]=args[x].shape[1]

R=min(sizes_0)
C=max(sizes_1)
#smallest row, largest col

k=np.empty((R,C), dtype=np.ndarray)
#empty array, desired size

m=[k]*len(args)
#list of len(args) empty arrays of desired size


for x in args:
    for y in range(0,len(args)):

        x=x[0:R,:]
        #select only rows within min # of rows

        missing=C-x.shape[1]
        add=np.zeros((x.shape[0], missing))
        x=np.append(x, add, axis=1)
        #add 'missing' number of columns (zeros) to each array

        m[y]=x
        #save the newly-shaped array to m

print m
```

sample inputs

```
array([[3],
       [4],
       [5],
       [6]])

array([[4, 5, 7],
       [6, 7, 7]])
```

minimum # of rows in sample input arrays is 2, maximum # of columns in sample input arrays is 4 (in this case, both parameters happen to come from the second array)

so, expected output would be:

```
array([[3, 0, 0],
       [4, 0, 0]])

array([[4, 5, 7],
       [6, 7, 7]])
```

Comment: Can you add a sample case and explain the expected result?

Comment: sure!

sample input would be:

np.array([3], [4], [5], [6])     and     np.array([[4, 5, 7],[6, 7, 7]])

; the least number of rows in the two inputs is two,
and the greatest number of columns is 3,

so the expected outputs would be:
np.array([3, 0, 0], [4, 0, 0])     and    np.array([[4, 5, 7],[6, 7, 7]])

Comment: Please add those into the question as they are not readable in comments.

Comment: oops, added to question! @Divakar